# How to detect whether the user has selected an item on a ListView?

Tags: java, listview, javafx, properties, listener

I have a `ListView` with items in it, and to go to the next page, the user must select an item, because the next page is about modifying the selected item.

To go to the next page, the user clicks a button labeled "Next". I have this grayed out by default, but I'd like it to be un-grayed the moment the user clicks on an element in the `ListView`.

At the moment, I have it set on `onMouseClick` which isn't very effective because this activates quite literally whenever the `ListView` *node* is clicked, not when an *element* is.

How would I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the [original tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/list-view.htm), section "Processing the List Item Selection" (Example 11-5).

```
listView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal) -> {
    // newVal contains the selected item
});
```

Also you can bind [`disableProperty`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#disableProperty) of the `Button` to the [`selectedItemProperty`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/SelectionModel.html#selectedItemProperty) of the selection model of the `ListView` conditionally:

```
nextButton.disableProperty().bind(listView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().isNull());
```